# Filtering big array of Objects with Ramda (or other functional library) using indexOf?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, functional-programming, ramda.js

I love Ramda, but sometimes i stumble in seemingly simple things.
What i have, is a list of places and words i need to look into (their indexOf must be equal to 0) to generate a list of search suggestions, so for example, given the list below, i would like to suggest to a user all 3 areas (by name) when they type 'aber' in the search box but only Aberdeen North if they type 'nor'.

```
[
  {
    name: "Aberavon",
    words: [ "aberavon" ]
  },
  {
    name: "Aberconwy",
    words: [ "aberconwy" ]
  },
  {
    name: "Aberdeen North",
    words: [ "aberdeen", "north" ]
  },
]
```

I managed to get the 'proper' thing running getting my results through console log, however i do not seem to get the filtered items. My code looks like this and the console logs will correctly show the iteration going through the words and the indexOf matching the start of a term but i never get my objects back out of the filter. I tried to make it even more functional and even more non-functional to no result so far! This is my code:

```
var matches = R.filter ( function ( x ) { R.map ( function ( word ) {
        console.log ( word );
        console.log ( word.indexOf ( term ) === 0 );
        R.equals ( word.indexOf ( term ), 0 )
    } ) ( x.words ) } ) ( json );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like the previous answer quite a bit, but if you want to see how a Ramda person does it, this would be my solution:

```
const startsWith = R.curry((term, word) => word.indexOf(term) === 0);
const anyStartsWith = R.curry((term, words) => R.any(startsWith(term), words));
const anyWordMatches = R.curry(
  (term, place) => anyStartsWith(term, R.prop('words', place))
);
const anyPlaceMatches = R.curry(
  (term, places) => R.filter(anyWordMatches(term), places)
);

anyPlaceMatches('nor', json); 
//=> [ <Aberdeen North> ]
anyPlaceMatches('aber', json); 
//=>[ <Aberavon>, <Abercrombie>, <Aberdeen North> ]
```

While all of this can probably be made point-free, I don't see the, ahem, point of that.

You can see all this in the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.23.0#?const%20json%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%7B%20name%3A%20%22Aberavon%22%2C%20words%3A%20%5B%20%22aberavon%22%20%5D%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%20name%3A%20%22Aberconwy%22%2C%20words%3A%20%5B%20%22aberconwy%22%20%5D%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%20name%3A%20%22Aberdeen%20North%22%2C%20words%3A%20%5B%20%22aberdeen%22%2C%20%22north%22%20%5D%20%7D%2C%0A%5D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20startsWith%20%3D%20R.curry%28%28term%2C%20word%29%20%3D%3E%20word.indexOf%28term%29%20%3D%3D%3D%200%29%3B%0Aconst%20anyStartsWith%20%3D%20R.curry%28%28term%2C%20words%29%20%3D%3E%20R.any%28startsWith%28term%29%2C%20words%29%29%3B%0Aconst%20anyWordMatches%20%3D%20R.curry%28%28term%2C%20place%29%20%3D%3E%20anyStartsWith%28term%2C%20R.prop%28%27words%27%2C%20place%29%29%29%3B%0Aconst%20anyPlaceMatches%20%3D%20R.curry%28%28term%2C%20places%29%20%3D%3E%20R.filter%28anyWordMatches%28term%29%2C%20places%29%29%3B%0A%0AanyPlaceMatches%28%27nor%27%2C%20json%29%3B%20%0A%2F%2F%3D%3E%20%5B%20%3CAberdeen%20North%3E%20%5D%0AanyPlaceMatches%28%27aber%27%2C%20json%29%3B%20%0A%2F%2F%3D%3E%5B%20%3CAberavpn%3E%2C%20%3CAbercrombie%3E%2C%20%3CAberdeen%20North%3E%20%5D%0A)**.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks a lot, will have to dissect this but it looks great!

Answer (score 3):

Not a Ramda expert, but I might be able to help.

The function (first argument) you pass to `R.filter` should take an `object` and return a `bool`.

The key is to create this method in a readable and reusable way. Eventually, you'll end up with something like:

- Go from an object `{}` to an array of strings `[string]`
- Go from an array of strings `[string]` to a boolean `bool`

### Step 1: Checking if a `word` matches a `term`

Currently, you have defined a function that is basically your "starts with" test:

```
R.equals ( word.indexOf ( term ), 0 )
```

This function needs two strings to work: `word` and `term`. *(Technically they could be anything that implements `indexOf`, but let's stick to the example)*

I'd start by testing this method and giving it a name, so you know this part is "done" and works.

```
const startsWith = term => word => word.indexOf(term) === 0;
```

(Later, you can rewrite this to use the Ramda API and include other features like case (in)sensitivity. You might also want to annotate something like `string -> string -> bool`, but again, I don't know the Ramda way)

### Step 2: Checking if *some* string matches a `term`

Now that you can check if strings match a term, you'll need to find out if *at least one string in an array of strings* matches a term.

In plain javascript:

```
const anyStartsWith = term => arr => arr.some(startsWith(term));
```

I think the Ramda equivalent is [`R.any`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#any):

```
const anyStartsWith = term => R.any(startsWith(term));
```

Again, test this method and see if it performs like you want it to.

### Step 3: Check if a `Place` matches a term

This is the most complicated step. We need to go from an `object` with a `words` property to something our earlier defined filter methods can handle.

```
const placeMatchesTerm = term => place =>
  anyStartsWith(term) (place.words);
```

### Step 4: Filtering

Now, we have a function that takes a term and returns a function that takes a `Place`. This, we can use to filter our array of places directly:

```
const myPlaces = [ /* ... */ ];
const filter = (term, arr) => 
  arr.filter(placeMatchesTerm(term));

const aber = filter("aber", myPlaces);
const nor = filter("nor", myPlaces);
```

In a working example (without Ramda)

```js
// string -> string -> bool
const startsWith = term => word => word.indexOf(term) === 0;
// string -> [string] -> bool
const anyStartsWith = term => arr => arr.some(startsWith(term));
// string -> {} -> bool
const placeMatchesTerm = term => place => anyStartsWith(term) (place.words);
// string -> [{}] -> bool
const filter = term => arr => 
  arr.filter(placeMatchesTerm(term));

const aber = filter("aber")(getPlaces());
const nor = filter("nor")(getPlaces());

console.log("'Aber' matches", aber.map(p => p.name));
console.log("'Nor' matches", nor.map(p => p.name));

// Data
function getPlaces() {
  return [{name:"Aberavon",words:["aberavon"]},{name:"Aberconwy",words:["aberconwy"]},{name:"Aberdeen North",words:["aberdeen","north"]}];
}
```

In Ramda, it might be something like [this](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20startsWith%20%3D%20term%20%3D%3E%20R.pipe%28%0A%20%20R.indexOf%28term%29%2C%0A%20%20R.equals%280%29%0A%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20placeMatchesQuery%20%3D%20term%20%3D%3E%20R.pipe%28%0A%20%20R.prop%28%22words%22%29%2C%0A%20%20R.any%28startsWith%28term%29%29%0A%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20matchesAber%20%3D%20placeMatchesQuery%28%22aber%22%29%3B%0Aconst%20matchesNor%20%3D%20placeMatchesQuery%28%22nor%22%29%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log%28%22Aber%3A%22%20%2B%20R.filter%28matchesAber%2C%20places%28%29%29.length%29%3B%0Aconsole.log%28%22Nor%3A%22%20%2B%20R.filter%28matchesNor%2C%20places%28%29%29.length%29%3B%0A%0Afunction%20places%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20%20%5B%7Bname%3A%22Aberavon%22%2Cwords%3A%5B%22aberavon%22%5D%7D%2C%7Bname%3A%22Aberconwy%22%2Cwords%3A%5B%22aberconwy%22%5D%7D%2C%7Bname%3A%22Aberdeen%20North%22%2Cwords%3A%5B%22aberdeen%22%2C%22north%22%5D%7D%5D%3B%0A%7D), but again, I'm no expert. I'll add the Ramda tag to your question which makes it pretty likely someone will show up to show you the Ramda ways :)

Comment: I am very sorry that i had to accept the other answer as both are FANTASTIC! I realised shortly after posting my question what my problem was, and it was that the way all the steps were encapsulated there was no way to return the whole item, as the "starts with" test is at the deepest level. Since then i fixed it another way, but the way you documented your response is really going to help me with other things in the future. Kudos!!!